# "TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not int" when using the google calendar API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-calendar-api, typeerror

I am pretty new to coding and trying to create a voice assistant. everything is working fine but I don't know why I am getting this error

Python version: 3.9 64bit
windows version: 10 pro 64bit
I live in India and the timezone we follow is Asia, Kolkata(just telling if that is causing it)

So I have made two functions:
The first function `get_date` will take a speech-to-text converted string and then try to find the date we are talking about.

```
def get_date(text):
    '''
    This fuction will return date value in the form of MM/DD/YYY
    it will convert any phrases passes to a date value if it contains the required data
    :param text:
    :return:
    '''
    text = text.lower()
    today = datetime.date.today()

    # if the query contains 'today' simply return today's date
    if text.count('today') > 0:
        return today
    # if the query contains 'tomorrow' simply return tomorrow's date
    if text.count('tomorrow') > 0:
        return today + datetime.timedelta(1)

    month = -1
    day_of_week = -1
    day = -1
    year = today.year

    # looping over the given phrase
    for word in text.split():
        # if the phrase contains name of month find its value from the list
        if word in MONTHS:
            month = MONTHS.index(word) + 1
        # if the phrase contains day of teh week return day of the week from the list
        if word in DAYS:
            day_of_week = DAYS.index(word)
        # if the phrase contains the digit itself then convert it from str to int
        if word.isdigit():
            day = int(word)
        # again run a loop to get values of DAY_EXTENSIONS and then check if we have them in the word
        for ext in DAY_EXTENSIONS:
            x = word.find(ext)
            if x > 0:
                try:
                    day = int(word[:x])
                except:
                    pass

    # if given month is passed add to the year
    if month < today.month and month != -1:
        year = year+1

    # if only day is given then finding if month is this or the next
    if month == -1 and day != -1:
        if day < today.day:
            month = today.month + 1
        else:
            month = today.month

    # if only day of the week is provided then find the date
    if day_of_week != -1 and month == -1:
        current_day_of_week = today.weekday()
        diff = day_of_week - current_day_of_week

        if diff < 0:
            diff += 7
            if text.count('next') >= 1:
                diff += 7

        return today + datetime.timedelta(diff)
    if day != -1:
        return datetime.date(month=month, day=day, year=year)
```

Then I have a second function which uses the google calendar API to get the events in the calendar
I don't know much about this but I am following a guy on youtube.
here is the function

```
def get_events(day, service):
    # the below four lines convert the date we provide in terms of utctime format
    # If you know what they really mean tell me, please 
    date = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.min.time())
    end = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.max.time())
    utc = pytz.UTC
    date = date.astimezone(utc)
    end = end.astimezone(utc)

    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=date.isoformat(),
                                          timeMax=end.isoformat(), singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
```

here is how I use these functions:

```
query = take_command().lower()
for phrases in GET_DATE_STRINGS:
    if phrases in query.lower():
        day = datetime.date(get_date(query))
        get_events(day, service)
```

and then here is the error:

```
<googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object at 0x00000189C9F60AC0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Coding\jarvis\main.py", line 248, in <module>
    get_events(3, service)
  File "D:\Coding\jarvis\main.py", line 157, in get_events
    date = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.datetime.min.time())
TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not int
```

Now according to me, the error is that the day input that I am giving to the `get_events()` function is int but as I can see the return function in the `get_date(`) returns a `DateTime.date` object not an int.
kindly help If you know the fix.

Answer (score 0):

If `get_date` returns a `date` object why are you again creating a `date` object here:
`day = datetime.date(get_date(query))` ?

You can just do:

```
day = get_date(query)
get_events(day, service)
```

Comment: I have tried this even without it but no luck (actually it was like that only) but I thought this would fix it but no, it didnt.

Comment: no the same one. I copied the code from the guy and then compared it word by word these two functions are exactly the same. I even replaced it with my code. my code still gets error but his code is working idk why.here is the link to my full code: https://github.com/Dynocoder/jarvis/blob/main/main.py

Comment: but the error remained the same even after changing and replacing the code

Comment: sorry, I didn't read your comment properly.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I tried replacing the functions I wrote with the functions that guy wrote, but even after that I get the same error. But when I use his full code (not only these two functions, but the full code) It works fine and does what it should do

Comment: I can't access the above github link, probably it's private. I am pretty sure there's some difference b/w your and that guy's code.

Comment: My bad I made it private here it is: https://github.com/Dynocoder/test/blob/main/main.py. also to save your time let me tell you that all the other feature functions like wishme, speak, takecommand , searchwiki are working fine. and have already been tested.

Comment: Can I see other guy's code?
You can actually debug this yourself. Use a debugger statement - `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside the `get_date` function and step through each line and observe the variable values till you reach the return statement.
The error clearly shows that for some reason `get_events` is receiving `3`, an int instead of a `date` object. For a start, print the output of `get_date`. If it's a number you can try the debugger - https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Comment: I created another file and copied the get_date() function and created all the pre-requisite variables and lists. then I did something like this `x = get_date(text)` (text is a string that says 'what do I have on Monday) and then I printed its type using this `print(type(x)) and it gave an output like this `<class 'DateTime.date'>` which according to me is a datetime.date object

Comment: here is his code: https://github.com/Dynocoder/test/blob/main/test.py. let me tell you that I don't have all the features he has and he doesn't have all the features I have